# Fitted Arima Model with NA values

Tags: r, na

Hey i have a short question about fitting an arima model with R. I have a large dataset with multiple NA Values which i can not remove.

So need to figure a way to model my data with arima with those missing values.
So with the help of the AIC Value I figured that the best model is an Arima 2,0,2 but if I try to fit this model I get the result: Null

Does anyone has an idea how I can work with that?

My code to fit the model is

```
fitted(final.arima)
```

I tried everything i know to work with the missing values

Comment: Can you post your data and code? I tried this using the `usconsumption` dataset as an example and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the code I use but I can not give you the dataset I use ...
daten1<-test

```
final.aic <- Inf

final.order <- c(0,0,0)

for (p in 0:2) for (q in 0:2) for(z in 0:1) {

   current.aic <- AIC(arima(daten1, order=c(p, z, q)))

   if (current.aic < final.aic) {

     final.aic <- current.aic

     final.order <- c(p,z, q)

     final.arima <- arima(daten1, order=final.order)
   }
 }

final.aic
final.order
final.arima

acf(resid(final.arima))

Box.test(resid(final.arima), lag=20, type="Ljung-Box")


############RMSE und R² testen für ARIMA Model###############

ffa<-fitted(final.arima)

daten1.mean<-mean(daten1)

R1<-sum((ffa-daten1.mean)^2)

R2<-sum((daten1-ffa)^2)

Rsquared<-R1/(R1+R2)

Rsquared
```